# Calculating limits of degree 'n'

Tags: limits

I am just grasping the concept of limits and can't find any website to help explain the solution to this limit.

I have found the answer which was 2, but it was guess and check as I saw that as $n$ got larger and larger it got closer and closer to 2.

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left({2-\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)^n}\right)$$

Can someone please show me step by step all formulas taken to solve this mathematically rather than what I did to get the answer

Comment: The limit in that case is note 2. I Guess you mean $(\frac{5}{9})^n$ and not $\frac{5^n}{9}$, right?

Comment: @macydanim: That was just poor typesetting; VikeStep wrote `\frac{5}{9}^n` which comes out looking the same as `\frac{5^n}{9}`.

Comment: @VikeStep Do you know that $\displaystyle \left( \frac{5}{9}\right)^n\longrightarrow 0$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles yes I thought so, just wanted to clearify my assumption.

Comment: Sorry guys, never used typesetting before and didn't know how to use it.

The purpose of finding this out was to find out the area of a fractal after an infinite number of iterations that used that formula to find the area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your formula reads $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (2 -\Bigl(\frac{5}{9}\Bigr)^n)$$
Obviously, the $2$ could be replaced by something else, so lets focus on 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Bigl(\frac{5}{9}\Bigr)^n$$
I will proof, that the limit of the sequence is $0$. 
If $0$ is the limit, this means that
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon>0: \quad \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \quad\text{such that} \quad \forall n>N: |x_n-x|<\epsilon
\end{align}
Where $x$ is the limit. This reads: Take a small number, then there exists $N$ such that for all numbers larger than $N$ the distance of the sequence $x_n$ to the limit is smaller than the small number.
In our case we need to show that 
\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon>0: \quad \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \quad\text{such that} \quad \forall n>N: \Bigr(\frac{5}{9}\Bigl)^n<\epsilon
\end{align}
So simply choose $N = \lfloor\log_{\frac{5}{9}}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1$. Here $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ means that you take the next integer below your number, e.g. $\lfloor 3.141\rfloor=3$. Therefore $0$ is the limit of the above sequence. Shifting it by $2$ gives the result.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the Latex command for floor or ceil. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

As the the other commenters have said you get that the  $\lim(\frac{5}{9})^n$ ends up going to zero as $n$ goes to $\infty$. You're only left with $2$ So you had a good intuition.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is indeed $2$.  The reason is that in general, if $a$ is a number such that $-1 < a < 1$ then
$$\lim_{a \to \infty}a^n = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can check that if $0<a<1$ then $a^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Let $ a=1/b$ as $a<1$ so $b>1$

Let $b=1+c$ where $c>0$ so using binomial theorem we have ,

$b^n=(1+c)^n\geq 1+nc$(as $(1+c)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}C(n,i)c^i\ge1+nc$(as c is positive))

So we have ,

$0<a^n=\frac{1}{b^n}=\frac{1}{(1+c)^n}\le\frac{1}{(1+nc)}<\frac{1}{nc}=(1/c)\frac{1}{n}$

Now by squeeze theorem we have,

$0\le\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n\le c_1\lim_{n\to \infty}(1/n)=0$(Note that the $<$ sign changes into$\le$ on taking limits)

Implying $\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n=0$

In the given question take $a=5/9$ ten you have $\lim_{n\to \infty}(5/9)^n=0$

So $\lim_{n\to \infty}(2-(5/9)^n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(2)-lim_{n\to \infty}(5/9)^n=2$